# In the performance's point of view: will C++ 11 perform better than its predecessors

Tags: c++, c++11

I know that C++ 11 and later ones provide a lot of hands-on tools that make developers easier to work. However, in the performance's point of view, will C++ 11 perform better than its predecessors?

For an instance, C++ 11's std::thread can work cross-platforms but in C++ 0x we have to make a wrapper for both Windows and Linux. In terms of performance, will std::thread perform better?

Comment: `std::thread` is a wrapper over native thread. So in terms of performance it shouldn't make any difference (except for possible overheads).

Comment: std::thread is just an example. We have many other things, right?

Comment: One clear performance gain in favour of C++11 onwards is move semantics.  `final` facilitates compile-time resolution of some virtual dispatch situations. C++11 was also the first Standard to officially introduce hash tables, though implementations were/are available for C++03.

Comment: Yes there are other things, but it is too broad to discuss everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several C++11 features, namely move semantics, can result in dramatic performance improvement. But mostly for code that's explicitly written to take advantage of it.

But a lot of the performance improvements will also automatically be in scope for unmodified code, as the compiler will be able to automatically deduce where move semantics, and other new language features, can be used.

But, for best results, write your code to explicitly take advantage of C++11's features.

Some performance improvements will be indirect. Other language features make it easier, and faster, to write optimal code; I specifically have `constexpr` in mind. This often results in better performance, too.

Answer (score 2):

C++11's main performance benefits are support for move construction/assignment and standard specified copy-elision. The latter improves a lot of code for free, and the former still benefits existing code that is recompiled using the STL collections and other standard types (which will often support and benefit from move semantics even if the code using them doesn't explicitly opt in; the benefits are limited without the code explicitly using `std::move` and the like appropriately, but still there).

The vast majority of the rest of it is essentially syntactic sugar to my knowledge (`std::thread` is just wrapping existing threading APIs; it's largely templated/inlined, so overhead is trivial or nonexistent, but neither is it somehow gaining you a performance benefit). That said, runtime performance is often less important than developer cycles; the syntactic sugar is a huge benefit because it means it's easier to write C++11. The existence of `auto` alone means that templates can do much more complex things, without forcing the developer to write absurd declarations describing what the template is doing; they just use `auto` and let type deduction figure it out.